# Blueimp Codeigniter image upload ajax 500 internal server error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, blueimp

I am trying to implement blueimp to my codeigniter project for multiple image upload of images. **i am facing 500 (internal server error) i know this appears if we have any error in our php script.**
in my php script i am getting response as **{"files":[]}** to represent no of img's which are present in my img_upload folder. it have to return null object thats true but

in my console i am getting a error as the below image.
[image]

as i clicked on anonymous function Here in my.js redirecting me to below function.

```
        $.ajax({
        // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
        //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
        url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
        dataType: 'json',
        context: $('#fileupload')[0]
    }).always(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('fileupload-processing');
    }).done(function (result) {
        $(this).fileupload('option', 'done')
            .call(this, $.Event('done'), {result: result});
    });
```

what i am thinking is this might be issue with return type html or json but not able to to get how to fix this issue. how can i solve this issue so i can upload image without getting internal error. Thanks in advance.

I am following the following github wiki and my code is same to same.

[This blog](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/jQuery-File-Upload,---Multi-file-upload-with-CodeIgniter)

Comment: add your backend php code please

Answer (score 1):

[may be its php.ini problem](https://gist.github.com/zitoloco/1558423)

Open your php.ini file

search for extension=php_fileinfo.dll

if you are using xampp it may be commented by default

change

```
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll

to

extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

and restart your xampp...

this was solve my problem

Comment: Solved my problem, I've been looking for a solution for 2 days!
In my case, I upgraded to CI3 and the problem appeared and I couldn't upload anything.